# how can i find the emails between two given dates, in gmail using python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make an email parser for gmail using python. i want to filter emails between two given dates (the start and the end date). How do i filter the emails?

i have tried something which gives me all the mails of the inbox but i want the mails only between the specified dates

Below is the part of the code:

```
import imapclient

import pprint

imapObj = imapclient.IMAPClient('imap.gmail.com', ssl=True)

email_id = input("Please enter your email_id: ")

import getpass

pswd = getpass.getpass('Password:')

print(imapObj.login(email_id, pswd))

imapObj.select_folder('INBOX', readonly=True)


UIDs = imapObj.gmail_search('cryptography') #for searching the mails related to the given key

UIDs = imapObj.search(['ALL']) #for searching all the mails

UIDs = imapObj.search(['SINCE 05-Jul-2018 ']) #i tried this but it is not working

print(UIDs)
```

Comment: Although `imapclient` makes this easier -  you'll still want to familiarise yourself with [RFC 3501](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501) - You'll want `SINCE` not `AFTER` and I *think* you need to give search pairs of search criteria... so it'd be `.search(['SINCE', '05-Jul-2018'])` (or whatever the correct date format is)

Comment: I haven't used it in ages, but you might also find that `imapclient` converts date/datetime objects accordingly for you... so using `datetime.date(2018, 7, 5)` as the second argument instead of a string - it might do the necessary conversion for you.

Comment: thanks Jon. Now the code is working as expected. but could you please help me on how to provide a pair of dates, i.e, i want to filter the mails between the two given dates. the above solution you mentioned is working fine in filtering the mails after the mentioned date. how can i provide the start and the end date?

Comment: I'm going to guess (don't have time to look it up but it rings a vague memory) you can do: `.search(['SINCE', '05-Jul-2018', 'BEFORE', '30-Jul-2018'])` ?

Comment: Probably also worth having a look at https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/api.html#imapclient.IMAPClient.search

Comment: it is working fine. thanks Jon!

Comment: Great to hear - I've put that as an answer then as these kind of things might well be useful for someone later wondering the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a list of search terms, eg:

```
UIDs = imapObj.search(['SINCE', '05-Jul-2018', 'BEFORE', '30-Jul-2018'])
```